# how do i use workbench to connect to a mysql DB?

Tags: sql, mysql

i am trying to connect to my local db using workbench but i do not see any way to connect. how do i do it? i already have this connection saved and succesfully tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workbench 5.1

Under the "Database" menu item, use the "Reverse Engineer" `CTRL+R`, "Forward Engineer" `CTRL+G` or "Synchronise Model" `CTRL+Y` options depending on what action you wish to carry out.

I would imagine that you would most likely wish to use Reverse Engineer as it allows you to generate and amend a visual model of an existing schema.

### Workbench 5.2

On the "Home" tab (`View > Home`) connections are listed under the "SQL Development"  heading on the far left-hand side of the screen.

To open a connection from here you either need to double-click the connection itself or click on "Open Connection to start Querying" which should present you with another window from which to select a connection, set usernames/password etc.

Comment: i dont have a home tab and when i go to view, home is not listed there. i am using 5.1